# Passing data from JavaScript to PHP via POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I can’t send the variable `lvl_id`. I put it inside the JavaScript and I want to pass it to PHP. Below is my `sort.php` and I want to pass it to `manageusersort.php`.

`sort.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").load(
        "manageusersort.php",
        {'page': 0},
        function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');}
    );  //initial page number to load

    $(".paginate_click").click(function(e) {
        $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');
        var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); // ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
        var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]);         // clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need

        $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active');     // remove any active class
        // post page number and load returned data into result element
        // notice (page_num-1), subtract 1 to get actual starting point
        $("#results").load(
            "manageusersort.php",
            {'page': (page_num-1)},
            $.POST("manageusersort.php", { lvl_id: "'<?php $lvlid=$_POST['lvlid']; echo $lvlid;?>'"}),
            function() {$('.paginate_click').removeClass('active');}
        );

        $(this).addClass('active');    // add active class to currently clicked element (style purpose)
        return false;                  // prevent going to href link
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's just a code-dump. What's your question? Please see **[Ask]**.

Comment: please advise what you are asking for help with.

Comment: exactly where is the queston you bought here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
$("#results").load(
    "manageusersort.php",
    {'page': (page_num-1)},
    function() {$('.paginate_click').removeClass('active');}
);
```

already passes some data to `manageusersort.php`. It looks like you then put this right in the middle:

```
$.POST("manageusersort.php", { lvl_id: "'<?php $lvlid=$_POST['lvlid']; echo $lvlid;?>'"}),
```

That'll do something separate. You probably want to hook into your original one:

```
$("#results").load(
    "manageusersort.php",
    {'page': (page_num-1), lvl_id: /* ... */},
    function() {$('.paginate_click').removeClass('active');}
);
```

Comment: thanks but still it doesnt display the database